# I get connection failed when i try to read my emails with laravel-imap

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, imap, laravel-9

I am having the following problem using laravel-imap to retrieve my emails. This error is:

**connection failed**

I describe what I did:

1. *Install with composer*

`composer require webklex/laravel-imap`

2. *Configuration*

```
IMAP_HOST=imap.gmail.com
IMAP_PORT=993
IMAP_ENCRYPTION=ssl
IMAP_VALIDATE_CERT=true
IMAP_USERNAME=myemail@example.com
IMAP_PASSWORD=mypassword
IMAP_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=default
IMAP_PROTOCOL=imap
```

3. *Route:*
   `Route::get('/reademail', [ClientController::class, 'imapMail'])->name('email.read');`
4. *Controller:*

```
$oClient = Client::account('default');
        $oClient->connect();        
        $oFolder = $oClient->getFolders();       
        dd($oFolder);
```

The problem is found on the line:

```
$oClient->connect();
```

I'm freaking out but I can't fix it. Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: Can you get information from the log, if it logged? Typically it is in `storage/logs`

Comment: what exactly should i see?

Comment: 70% likely to be a firewall issue.

Comment: I solved the problem. I just set IMAP_VALIDATE_CERT to false.